# How to make variable exclusive to class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, inheritance

Lets say this is my code:

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.purs = True
        self.hasFur = True

class HairlessCat(Cat):
    def __init__(self):
        Cat.__init__(self)

jeffery = Cat()
bob = HairlessCat()
```

how can I make it so `jeffery` has fur and `bob` does not (and all future `Cat`s have fur and `HairlessCat`s don't)?

Update: Not via changing it through `HairlessCat` but making it so `Cat` does not give any other classes inheritance towards `self.hasFur`.

Comment: You can't really block inheritance without bending over backwards significantly, which is rarely a good idea. The sane OO thing to do is to define both a `HairyCat` and a `HairlessCat` as distinct subspecies of `Cat` (or make the base cat hairless and make hairiness an explicit subspecies). With inheritance you want to go more specific in each child, not roll back previous declarations of the parent.

Answer (score 3):

Use class variables. A subclass that defines a variable name similar to that contained in its base class will override the value:

```
class Cat:
    hasFur = True

    def __init__(self):
        self.purs = True

class HairlessCat(Cat):
    hasFur = False
```

in this case you also don't need to define `__init__` for the subclass since, you don't change anything.

Any instances created from `HairlessCat` will have the attribute `hasFur` set to `False` and any of `Cat` to `True`.